# How to use Url.Action in iframe src

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iframe, url-action

How to use the `Url.Action` method in the `iframe` `src` attribute. Like

```
<iframe src = '<%=Url.Action("HelloWorld", "myController");%>' width = "100%" height="1000" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

But its not working properly. Its saying that the requested content is not available.

Please help me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using ASP.NET engine

```
<iframe src = '<%: Url.Action("HelloWorld", "myController") %>' width = "100%" 
    height="1000" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Using razor engine.

```
<iframe src = '@Url.Action("HelloWorld", "myController")' width = "100%" 
    height="1000" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Same here found error in getting what type of Controller should be? so this is the best solution if you are using IFrame for PDF Viewer and I hope this code will be useful.


<iframe src="@Url.Action("GetPDF")" id="sign" width="800" height="800"></iframe>

  public FileStreamResult GetPDF()
        {
            var path = "E:\\FirstTask\\FirstTask\\FolderToSave\\Patient Consent.pdf";
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            return File(fs, "application/pdf");
        }
```